# How to use ZK with Grails' controllers

Tags: grails, zk

So far I've looked at the ZKGrails and ZKUI plugins, and I'm not convinced I want to go either route.  My understanding is that ZKGrails doesn't make use of Grails' controllers at all, and ZKUI makes an attempt at using Grails' controllers, but still defers some of the view controlling to the ZK composers.  What I'm looking for is a way to leverage Grails' controller scaffolding and views, while embedding ZK components in those Grails views.  Anyone have any resources or ideas to help with this?

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you need pure grails controller instead of composer or semi-grails-controller provided by ZK Grails/ZKUI? You can do everything in these what you would in a grails controller unless I am missing something or misunderstood your question.

Comment: My thought is that it would be best to mitigate the number of files necessary for Grails's CRUD operations when using ZK components within .gsp files.  Having both controllers and composers seemed like unnecessary complexity at first that could lead to more places for error, but I think I'm buying into the controller/composer more now.  A confusing aspect to ZKGrails is that it offers a mechanism to create viewmodels in addition to controllers and composers.  I'm surprised that ZK doesn't have a specific "ZK Grails" project similar to their "ZK Spring" or "ZK JSP" projects.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think your requirement can be met with existing ZK Grails/ZKUI. Both seem to have scaffolding support but

- Scaffolding for ZK Grails check slide 19~20 from [here](http://code.google.com/p/zkgrails/)
- Static scaffolding for ZKUI check [here](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2012/January/Ajax_GSP_with_ZK#Static_Scaffolding)

However scaffolding in both these solutions are not true grails scaffolding as in grails controllers embedded with UI components